# c# multithreading - shared Bitmap, locks and semaphores

Tags: c#, multithreading, bitmap, locking

Currently I have a Form with pictureBox. The Form draws 3 orbitals going in circles around the cursor. Each 'Orbital' is a separate object with it's own thread updating position every 1 degree rotation, depending on orbital's specific parameters. In main program, I call drawing function for each orbital, depending on the fastest one, so it don't stutters.

Now, everything is fine, but I can't get the Bitmap to be accessed by only one thread at a time. Adding semaphores / locks, delays the "currently in use elsewhere" error, but doesn't prevent it. The lock (/ semaphore) is passed to every Orbital in constructor.

Here's the code for updating called in thread refreshing the display:

```
private void UpdateDisplay()
    {
        // get fresh display
        Lock.AcquireWriterLock(-1);
            Display = (Bitmap)(Background.Clone());
        Lock.ReleaseWriterLock();
        // draw all orbitals
        foreach (Orbital item in Orbitals)
        {
            item.Draw(Display);
        }
        // update the display
        Lock.AcquireWriterLock(-1);
            pictureBox1.Image = Display;
        Lock.ReleaseWriterLock();
    }
```

And this is the Draw method of object Orbital:

```
    public void Draw(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        // draw a square 
        int maxX = OrbitalX + OrbitalSizeRadius;
        int maxY = OrbitalY + OrbitalSizeRadius;
        for (int i = OrbitalX - OrbitalSizeRadius; i < maxX; i++)
        {
            for (int j = OrbitalY - OrbitalSizeRadius; j < maxY; j++)
            {
                Lock.AcquireWriterLock(-1);
                    // check for eventual offscreen pixels
                    if (BoundaryControl.Check(i, j, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height))
                    {
                        bitmap.SetPixel(i, j, OrbitalColor);
                    }
                Lock.ReleaseWriterLock();
            }
        }
    }
```

I thought that locking / waiting, is pseudo-atomical, but from the looks of it, it's not, unless I'm understanding these wrong way.

EDIT:

More detail about error. Always jumps out at the line `pictureBox1.Image = Display;`, at random times: after half of a spin up to few full spins.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Object is currently in use elsewhere.
```

Code regarding handling the lock, inside the Orbital:

```
// declaration
private ReaderWriterLock Lock;

// constructor
public Orbital(int radius, double speed, int sizeRadius, Color color, int startingRotation, bool counterClockwise, ReaderWriterLock thelock)
    {
        /*
         * bunch of assigns
         */
        Lock = thelock;
    }
```

Inside the Form class:

```
// declaration
private ReaderWriterLock Lock;

// initialization
Lock = new ReaderWriterLock();

// passing to Orbital as an argument
// Orbitals is an ArrayList
Orbitals.Add(new Orbital(100, 10, 5, Color.IndianRed, 0, false, Lock));
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting, and one what line? `"currently in use elsewhere"` isn't very helpful.. Are you sure you are only using 1 lock? Maybe you accidentally made 3 locks and passed a different one to each thread instead of the same one.

Comment: Just out curiosity, is there a particular reason you chose multiple threads all writing to a shared bitmap?  I only ask as this approach is pretty atypical. Most common solution is to have a single draw thread walk through your data structure and redraw everything as needed.

Comment: @LeeHiles, I wanted to keep Draw inside the Orbital in case I wanted to get specific subclass drawing method. I would also have to throw all the information to the main program, but that's minor. I don't know, seemed like a decent idea.

Comment: I think it's the left side of `pictureBox1.Image = Display` that is throwing not the right side, because your bitmap locks look fine to me. You appear to be using a lock because `Display` is the bitmap, but I bet it's `pictureBox1` that is being accessed from multiple threads and is throwing. Try adding locks around any other `pictureBox1`'s, as well as any other references to the same object that it is referencing.

Comment: @Quantic, could this be `pictureBox1.MouseMove += PictureBox1_MouseMove;` ? This is the only other operation on pictureBox I'm doing (and it only updates mouse position for Orbital calculations) and it would seem absurd since in previous program with only one orbital with data within the main program, thread to update position and 3 events strapped to pictureBox (halving the radius and speed on LMB hold), everything worked perfectly without errors.

Comment: Well I'm no expert with events and how they work but yes, it's very possible and even common that the probability of `pictureBox1` being accessed by two threads was extremely small until you added more threads. I've had programs that were not threadsafe but it took days of testing for something to throw. Comment your `pictureBox1.MouseMove += PictureBox1_MouseMove;` line and try again.

Comment: You can also try this: `pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(width, height);`; if it throws then it has nothing to do with your `Orbital` code. In which case I assume that yes, `pictureBox1.MouseMove += PictureBox1_MouseMove;` is causing the problem.

Comment: Changed target to panel, center got stuck at (0, 0), but w/e. They are still spinning, and program still throws that error at that line. I'm currently rebuilding it to keep possibility of individual drawing but Draw inside the main program as suggested above. But it is still very interesting situation. :)

Comment: Found the root of the problem, apparently I'm an idiot and I used form as a parameter for the main thread updating display. Sorry to be a bother, and thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved, Locks work perfectly fine. Sharing Display was indeed a problem, but solving it 'revealed' another hidden problem that throws exactly the same error.